# Using the jenkins CLI (on fedora 23)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, fedora-23

I have a jenkins instance running.  To create this instance on a Fedora 23 machine, I installed jenkins (via dnf) and started it (via systemd).  It is running and I can see it in my browser at http://localhost:8080.

I have been trying to follow the directions in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI.

I download http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar to my computer.

Then I try to run the program `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar http://127.0.0.1 -s help` and I get `no main manifest attribute, in jenkins-cli.jar`

When I check jenkins-cli.jar, sure enough there is no `Main-Class` entry in the manifest file.

What is the proper way to invoke the jenkins cli?

Addendum
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins has a separate procedure for using the jenkins cli, but it does not explain where to obtain jenkins.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a kludgy solution.  I hope someone has a better idea.

On my instance I run

```
curl http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/localizer/localizer-1.9.jar.zip > localizaer-1.9.jar.zip
unzip localizaer-1.9.jar.zip
curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar > commons-code-1.9.jar
java -classpath /usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar:/usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/remoting.jar:/usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/slave.jar:/usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/classes:localizer-1.9.jar:commons-code-1.9.jar:localizer-1.9.jar hudson.cli.CLI -s http://localhost:8080 help
```

I don't like it because it is super-kludgy, but it seems to work.